# Testing how faster/slower are commands in R

Tags: r, percentage, processing-efficiency, microbenchmark

I am trying to figure out how fast/slow each of the following operations are for calculating the cumulative sum from 1 to 100.

```
install.package('microbenchmark')
library(microbenchmark)

#Method 1
cs_for = function(x) {
  for (i in x) {
    if (i == 1) {
      xc = x[i]
    } else {
      xc = c(xc, sum(x[1:i]))
    }
  }
  xc
}

cs_for(1:100)

# Method 2: with apply (3 lines)
cs_apply = function(x) {
  sapply(x, function(x) sum(1:x))
}

cs_apply(100)

# Method 3: 
cumsum (1:100)

microbenchmark(cs_for(1:100), cs_apply(100), cumsum(1:100))
```

The output I get is the following one:

```
Unit: nanoseconds
          expr   min     lq      mean   median     uq    max neval cld
 cs_for(1:100) 97702 100551 106129.05 102500.5 105151 199801   100   c
 cs_apply(100)  8700   9101  10639.99   9701.0  10651  54201   100  b 
 cumsum(1:100)   501    701    835.96    801.0    801   3201   100 a
```

This shows that the last method has the highest rank of efficiency in comparison to the other two. Just in the case, I am interested how much each method is faster (both in percentage and as a number of times it is faster), I would like to know which kind of operation you suggest to apply?

Comment: Try different input sizes. Also, strictly speaking your tests are not equivalent because your `cumsum` benchmark isn’t wrapped into a function `cs_cumsum` as the other two are. Lastly, I suggest you also benchmark `vapply` since `sapply` does some shenanigans that potentially make it less efficient.

Comment: Ok, I will try. Thanks. Could please t show me how I could get the rate (percentage) and the number of times a method is quicker or slower than the other one?

Comment: No, because neither of these questions are answerable. You’ll see why when you benchmark different input sizes and compare the runtimes across them (they’re not fixed multiples of one another). The technical term to look for is [asymptotic computational complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_computational_complexity) — be warned, it’s fairly technical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Be careful that you benchmark the correct thing: `cs_appy(100)` isn’t the same as `cs_for(100)`! It’s a shame that ‘microbenchmark’ doesn’t warn you of this. By contrast, the ‘bench’ package does:

   ```r
   bench::mark(cs_for(1 : 100), cs_apply(100), cumsum(1 : 100))
   # Error: Each result must equal the first result:
   # `cs_for(1:100)` does not equal `cs_apply(100)`
   ```
2. Be careful that your benchmark is representative: you are looking at a single data point (input of length 100), and it’s a *tiny* input size. The results are very likely to be dominated by noise, even with repeat measurements.
3. Always benchmark with several different input sizes to get an idea of the asymptotic growth. In fact, your question “how many times” one method is faster than the other doesn’t even make sense, because the different functions do not have the same asymptotic behaviour: two are linear, and one is quadratic. To see this, you *must* measure repeatedly. ‘microbenchmark’ doesn’t support this out of the box, but ‘bench’ does (but you could of course do it manually).
4. To perform an apples-to-apples comparison, the `cumsum()` benchmark should also be wrapped inside a function, and all functions should accept the same parameter (I suggest `n`, the size of the input vector).

Putting this all together, and using the ‘bench’ package, we get the following. I also added a benchmark using ‘vapply’, since that’s generally preferred to `sapply`:

```
cs_for = function (n) {
  x = 1 : n
  for (i in x) {
    if (i == 1L) {
      xc = x[i]
    } else {
      xc = c(xc, sum(x[1 : i]))
    }
  }
  xc
}

cs_apply = function (n) {
  sapply(1 : n, \(x) sum(1 : x))
}

cs_vapply = function (n) {
  vapply(1 : n, \(x) sum(1 : x), integer(1L))
}

cs_cumsum = function (n) {
  cumsum(1 : n)
}

results = bench::press(
    n = 10L ^ (1 : 4), # from 10 to 10,000
    bench::mark(cs_for(n), cs_apply(n), cs_vapply(n), cs_cumsum(n))
)
```

And since the first rule of data science is “visualise your results”, here’s a plot:

```
results |>
  mutate(label = reorder(map_chr(expression, deparse), desc(median))) |>
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = n, y = median, color = label) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  bench::scale_y_bench_time() +
  scale_x_log10()
```

[image: benchmark plot]

… As you can see, not all lines increase linearly. In fact, both `cs_for` and `cs_cumsum` increase super-linearly. `cs_for` has [quadratic runtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Polynomial_time) because progressively appending to the `xc` vector necessitates allocating new storage and copying over the old values. Both `apply` and `vapply` avoid this. You can also avoid this when using `for` by pre-allocating your result vector. The fact that `cumsum` *also* exhibits super-linear runtime actually surprises me — it definitely shouldn’t do that! This merits further investigation.

Comment: It's a very extended and well-described answer. So I can understand that there is no way numerical way (I mean just simply calculating with specific formula) to get how fast is a method than another? Because the textbook I'm consulting, reports that, as you could see as well in the table got with microbenchmark(), the last one is 300 times faster. And I misled why that it is.

Comment: There isn’t a single factor: the larger the n, the larger the factor. For example, for n=100, `sapply` is ~1.4x faster than `for`; but for n=1000, it’s already >6x faster. In fact, for small enough n (= 10), `sapply` is even *slower* than a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can work with the table of results by saving the summary:

```
results <- summary(microbenchmark(cs_for(1:100), cs_apply(100), cumsum(1:100)))
```

It's then straigtforward to do calculations on is such as working out how many times the median time is greater than the fastest median with:

```
results[,"median"]/min(results[,"median"])
# [1] 131.35714  14.14286   1.00000
```

Comment: Your calculation gives incorrect results, as the runtime of `cs_for` isn’t linear and thus doesn’t linearly relate to the other runtimes.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Your he accepted answer covers this well, but the question as written asks about comparing the approaches in the special case of n=100, rather than the general computational complexity with n.

Comment: Exactly. Indeed, as I posted down Konrad's answer, this will be about some formula to apply. But I cannot get which one should be. I thought that the rate between the first rank method and the other one wants to test for, should have been correct. But it is not